# Proof of generalized associative law in groups

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to prove a statement about associativity of $n$ group elements that Dummit and Foote leave leave as an exercise.

> For any $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n \in G$, the value of $a_1 * a_2 * \ldots * a_n$ is independent of how the expression is bracketed.

I was hoping someone could check over my attempt at a proof, which is my best attempt at understanding the proof in Dummit and Foote and a few proof explanations I found online.

**Proof.** We proceed by strong induction on $n$.

If $n=1$, the product $a_1$, a single element, is unambigously defined and possesses only a single form of parenthesization. If $n=2$, then $a_1 * a_2$ can, similarly, only be bracketed in a single way, and is well-defined by the definition of the binary operation $*$. If $n=3$, then we have $(a_1 * a_2) * a_3 = a_1 * (a_2 * a_3)$ by the associativity group axiom.

Now, we will proceed by strong induction, supposing $P(1), P(2), \ldots, P(n-1)$, where $n-1 \leq 3$ and hence $n \geq 4$. That is, we assume the result for all $k < n \leq 4$. I claim that we can convert any form of parenthesizing a product of $n$ elements into the form
$$b_1 * (b_2 * (b_3 * (\ldots * b_k)) \ldots ),$$
and if any such parenthesization can be converted to this form, it must be the case that they are all equal by transitivity of equality.

Consider the product of $n$ group elements $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ with some form of parenthesization.

(This is the part where I do not completely understand the proof, but I will try to explain it.)

We argue that we can break apart a product of $n$ elements into two "subproducts," $A$ and $B$. If, for example, we have a product of four elements of the form $a_1 (a_2 (a_3 a_4))$, then $A = a_1$ and $B = a_3 (a_3 a_4)$. If we have $(a_1 a_2) (a_3 a_4)$, then $A = a_1 a_2$ and $B = a_3 a_4$. If we have $(a_1 (a_2 a_3))a_4$, then $A = a_1 a_3 a_3$ and $B = a_4$.

(This is a somewhat simple example, but I'm hoping someone can explain it better than me.)

Generally, for some $m < n$, we break up the product in the form $A*B$ where $A = a_1 * a_2 * \ldots a_m$ and $B = a_{m+1} \cdot a_{m+2} \cdots a_n$, where we omit omit parentheses because we assumed that the product of $m$ elements is unambiguously defined and associative. Furthermore, by our strong induction hypothesis, the products in both $A$ and $B$ can be written as the right-associated expression.

We have two cases. First, we may have $m=1$, so $A = a_1$. If this is the case, our product of $n$ terms is written as a right-associated expression, and the proof is complete.

Now we suppose that $m \neq 1$. Considering $A$, since $m < n$, we can write its right-associated form, meaning we can take $a_1$ on the outside and write $a_1 * C$ for some product of $m-1$ terms, $C$. But then
$$A*B = (a_1 * C)*B.$$
But $a_1$, $C$, and $B$ are unambigously defined products by the induction hypothesis, so we can apply the associative law for three elements:
$$A*B = a_1 * (C*B).$$
$C*B$ has $n-1$ terms, so it can be written in its right-associative form, meaning that $A*B$ is written exactly in its right-associated form, which is the goal.

*Big question* The biggest question I have is whether the logic is sound and why and how we break a product of $n$ terms into two subproducts. In particular, what exactly breaking up relative to the "outermost" expression means.

Answer (score 1):

Any product of $n$ terms $x_1,...,x_n$ is defined by induction. If $n=1$, it is just $x_i$. If $n>1$ then it is a product of two elements $y,z$ where $y$ is a product of $m$ elements $x_1,...,x_m$ and $z$ is a product of $n-m$ elements $x_{m+1}...x_{n}$, $0<m<n$. So what you want to prove is just a definition. The rest is OK. See the definition of elements in the [free magma](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Free_magma)

Comment: why to divide at m ? why not have whole of $a_1a_2...a_n-1$ as A which can be written in any way by induction hypothesis and so we have $ A* (a_n)$= a_1 (a_2 (a_3(...a_n))))) .a_n $